# how can i set particles static until collision affects to them?

Tags: particles

I ask novice question.

I am trying to make sand simulation with molecular addon.

What I want to know is how to set particles tobe static until collision object

touch to particles.

When I bake simulation, particles never stop and keep slight moving.

I want sand to be as static until the monkey collied to sand.

I thought about maybe I should use cache, and use from collided frame,

but its also looks strange, non collided  particles are also start moving

from the frame.
I hope for any possible advices. thank you.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

I add link to .blend here.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Just set the friction to max, bouncing to lowest and the damping also to (i think) max - just try out. Just keyframe that values until your monkey touches, than you can change them on that keyframe. The touch of your monkey you can either manually set via keyframe, or e.g. by an invisible plane you insert there and then you know also, when it starts touching.

Comment: thankyou for the answer, i tried to keyframed the friction and damping value. (and also gravity)   now it looks more static, but still looks shivering,,

Comment: Can you provide blend file?

Comment: thank you for your reply. I will send in one hour.

Comment: I added .blend in my question post.  I am sorry for late.  it took while to reduce file size to put on Blend -Exchange.